# jQuery not executing when multiple json values are passed

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter

How do I pass multiple returned mysql rows through json to the below jquery script? With the code I have written so far I can't get the jquery success callback function to execute when i pass 2 or more to it. How would I go about accomplishing this?

jQuery, Js code:

```
$("#projects").click(function() {
    jQuery.ajax({ type: "POST", dataType: "JSON",
        url: "<?=base_url()?>index.php/home/projectsSlider",
        json: {returned: true}, success: function(data) {
            if (data.returned === true) {
                $("#content").fadeOut(150, function() {                             
                    $(this).replaceWith(projectsSlider(data.projectId, data.projectName, data.startDate, data.finishedDate, data.projectDesc, data.createdFor, data.contributors, data.screenshotURI, data.websiteURL), function() {
                        $(this).fadeIn(150);
                    });
                });
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Php code:

```
function projectsSlider() {
    $query  = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM projects ORDER BY idprojects DESC");
    foreach ($query->result() as $row) {
        $projectId = $row->projectId;
        $projectName = $row->projectName;
        $startDate = $row->startDate;
        $finishedDate = $row->finishedDate;
        $createdFor = $row->createdFor;
        $contributors = $row->contributors;
        $projectDesc = $row->projectDesc;
        echo json_encode(array('returned' => true,
            'projectId' => $projectId,
            'projectName' => $projectName,
            'startDate' => $startDate,
            'finishedDate' => $finishedDate,
            'projectDesc' => $projectDesc,
            'createdFor' => $createdFor,
            'contributors' => $contributors));
    }
    $query1 = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM screenshots s WHERE s.projectId = '{$projectId}' ORDER BY s.idscreenshot DESC");
    foreach ($query1->result() as $row2) {
        $screenshotURI = $row2->screenshotURI;
        $websiteURL = $row->websiteURL;
        echo json_encode(array('screenshotURI' => $screenshotURI,'websiteURL' => $websiteURL));
    }
}
```

Comment: reformat your code, please... all the indentation was lost :-(

Comment: @Benjamin Cox: there is a chance there was originally no indentation ;-)

Comment: No I did indent, but it looked horrible.

Comment: @zerkms LOL, I didn't even think of that ;-)

Comment: @Michael Grigsby: how is it possible to look even more horrible than now? ;-)

Comment: I'll do it - just wait a moment

Comment: You all could have asked me to just repost my code with the indention's included.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are echoing two different JSON strings. That will not a be a valid JSON. Hence (although I have not tested it), the ajax call will fail.

I suggest you merge the two JSONs and return just one valid JSON from the "projectsSlider()" function. 
Like so:

```
$projectArray = $this->getProjectsRowSet();
$screenshotsArray = $this->getScreenshotsRowSet();
$combinedArray = array_merge(array("Projects" =>$projectArray),array("Screenshots" =>$screenshotsArray));
echo json_encode($combinedArray);
```

Then access each of the rowsets from within the ajax callback method by using "data.Projects" and "data.Screenshots".
Like so:

```
$("#resultProjects").html(JSON.stringify(data.Projects));
$("#resultScreenshots").html(JSON.stringify(data.Screenshots));
```

Comment: http://i45.tinypic.com/30kacle.png - as you can tell I'm only getting one row returned. Here is my current PHP: http://pastebin.com/jGHUifJM - am I running the loop wrong or something or am I only restricted to sending one row through json?

Comment: Your foreach loops which iterate over the query results are wrong. Before your foreach loops for processing the $rows, you need to create an array. i.e. "$projectsArray = array()" Then you need to create new array for each row like "$projectArray = array();" and add that to your $projectsArray like "$projectsArray[] = $projectArray;".  I've added an amendment to your pastebin link. I've only done the changes for Projects, you need to do the same for the Screenshots.

Comment: Okay thanks man. Do you have the link to the new pastebin code? and let ask you something... How'd you become so smart at web development? and how long have you been doing this?

Comment: Ah lucky you lol. Wish I was doing it for that long. I've still got allot to learn I guess before I can even think about getting a job as a web developer. That's really good though. Anyway I'm still not getting all the returned rows as you can tell from the following pic: http://i49.tinypic.com/20hjxxi.png. Here is the edited PHP: http://pastebin.com/4Ep6XEa2. Also I plan to read up on how exactly jQuery ajax statements completely work for I'm not completely sure. But in the mean time, how can I code the success statement. Here is my code so far: http://pastebin.com/6tvdWwZV. Thanks a million.

Comment: Well, looks like you are on the right track with your learnings. Good luck. :) You have some curly braces in the wrong places and some variable names mixed up. I strongly suggest you look at your code carefully for these types of silly errors yourself first. Here's the pastebin link http://pastebin.com/5kZ8AG7U. I have not tested the fixed code, just fixed it by eye only.

Comment: Okay the PHP is working correctly now. I had to edit my SQL statement because I wasn't getting all the screenshots returned. Now the tricky part for me... Coding the success callback function. Obviously I won't be able to access the returned objects using, `success: function(data) {if (data.returned === true) {` anymore. So how would I access the values in the array? Thanks for all your help btw. I'm learning allot with your help :)

Comment: hey, you dont need the `data.returned === true....` Do it like this 
`success: function(data) {
$("#resultProjects").html(JSON.stringify(data.Projects));
$("#resultScreenshots").html(JSON.stringify(data.Screenshots));
}`

Comment: Okay and so do I access the objects like: data.Projects[0].projectId...?

Answer (score 1):

A valid JSON string is basically the right-hand side of an assignment statement in a block of JS code. You're generating multiple independent JSON strings within your foreach() loop, and are basically producing something like

```
var x = 1; 2; 3; 4; 5; 6;
```

which is a flat-out syntax error. You're generating unparseable json.

Your loop should build a single monolithic PHP data structure, which you then json_encode AFTER the loop finishes:

```
$data = array();
foreach($query1->result() as $row2) {
   $data[] = array($row2->screenshotURI, $row->websiteURL);
}
echo json_encode($data);
```

Comment: Okay, keep in mind I've got two separate foreach statements. Do I need to combine them or just include the new array code in each of them?

Comment: doesn't matter how many loops you have. in the end, you can output only a **SINGLE** json string, from a **SINGLE** json_encode() call.

Comment: So how deal with the fact I need to output multiple values from the db? Do I just try a different approach or will the code you are showing me solve this?

Comment: I don't know what your client-side requirements are, but it's easy enough to build complicated nested structures in PHP, and then that structure over as json. you'd have to modify your client-side code to handle that new structure, of course.

Comment: Do you know of any tutorials that explain that?

Comment: Not offhand... but what's to read up on? it's just a PHP array. You can nest arrays however deep you want, and mix objects/arrays as well.

Comment: Silly nitpicking: `var x = 1; 2; 3; 4; 5; 6;` isn't a syntax error, it's six separate statements the last five of which don't do anything useful. Also you _can_ use separate PHP statements to output pieces of the final JSON string a bit at a time, as long as you output appropriate commas or whatever in between. E.g., you could echo `[` then `{"id":1}` then `,` then `{"id":2}` then `]`.